# Remove header after ending section with officer - margins are set to zero

Tags: r, officer

I need to create a multi-page document where on page one I want to start directly from the very top.

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

my_doc <- read_docx('empty_with_footnotes.docx') 

font.size_space = 4

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar(ftext(
    paste0("\u00A0"),
    fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',
            font.size = font.size_space - 1, bold = TRUE)),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "right",
                  shading.color = 'darkgrey')), pos = 'on')

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar('Some Text',
                     fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "right",
                                   shading.color = 'darkgrey')))

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar(ftext(
    paste0("\u00A0"),
    fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',
            font.size = font.size_space, bold = TRUE)),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "right",
                  shading.color = 'darkgrey')))

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar(ftext(
    paste0("\u00A0"),
    fp_text(font.family = 'Calibri',
            font.size = font.size_space, bold = TRUE)),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "right")))

print(my_doc, target = 'file.docx')
```

The result is exactly what I need

[image]

As soon as I want to add a second page with a section, the header space appears

```
end_header <- block_section(
  prop_section(
    page_size =
      page_size(orient = "portrait"),
    type = "continuous",
    page_margins = page_mar(
      bottom = 0,
      top = 0.0,
      right = 0.05,
      left = 0.04,
      header = 0,
      footer = 0,
      gutter = 0
    )
  )
)

my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_end_block_section(end_header)


my_doc <- my_doc %>%
  body_add_fpar(fpar(
    #bold part
    ftext(paste0('Next Page'),
          fp_text(underlined = F, font.size = 9, font.family = "Calibri", italic = F, bold = TRUE)),
    
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "justify")), style=NULL)

print(my_doc, target = 'file2.docx')
```

The empty white line appear even though I specified in the block section margins = 0

[image]

Code and files can be found at https://github.com/aavanesy/officer_header

Comment: My sense is the problem is with your intent; you cannot (as far as I am aware) create a word document without a header. A better approach is to move the text into the header. Why? Well, I ran your code and noted that if you open file2, select "view header footer" in Word, and then click on the orange text, the text jumps up, and the header gap disappears. I could submit an answer on how to use the header but felt it better to describe the "feature" observed first. My sense from using officer would be to put the orange band and text in the header. I wanted to check with you on intent first.